# How to findById for uuid type ObjectId mongoose nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, uuid, binary-data

My mongo document objectId is of type UUID v4 and want to fetch it using findById.

When I fetch document using findOne({}) it returns document for uuid '2df8dcfa-05fc-4e33-bf98-a3a8684ca76f' and _id looks like

```
Binary {
  _bsontype: 'Binary',
  sub_type: 3,
  position: 16,
  buffer: <Buffer 33 4e fc 05 fa dc f8 2d 6f a7 4c 68 a8 a3 98 bf>
}
```

Any idea how can I convert my uuid(string) e.g '2df8dcfa-05fc-4e33-bf98-a3a8684ca76f' to above binary format and then apply findById on it?

Tried to use MUUID from https://github.com/cdimascio/uuid-mongodb/blob/master/example/ex4-mongoose.js but it convert uuid to sub-type 4 like below

MUUID.from('2df8dcfa-05fc-4e33-bf98-a3a8684ca76f') results in

```
Binary {
      _bsontype: 'Binary',
      sub_type: 4,
      position: 16,
      buffer: <Buffer 2d f8 dc fa 05 fc 4e 33 bf 98 a3 a8 68 4c a7 6f>,
      toString: [Function: bound ]
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

we were using spring boot with default UUID as JAVA UUID. But for libraries like UUID-MongoDB which uses standard UUID.

I wrote a converter function for that JAVA UUID to STANDARD UUID and vice versa. It was explained on this page https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/#complex-uuid-scenarios

But now we planning to migrate DB to standard UUID. so that both JAVA and NodeJs can access UUID's